# How to have only one thread for fire and forget task in asp.net webapi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, task-parallel-library, stackexchange.redis, background-task

I have a need in my asp.net webapi (framework .Net 4.7.2) to call Redis (using StackExchange.Redis) in order to delete a key in a fire and forget way and I am making some stress test.

As I am comparing the various way to have the max speed :

- I have already test executing the command with the FireAndForget flag,
- I have also measured a simple command to Redis by await it.
- And I am now searching a way to collect a list of commands received in a window of 15ms and execute them all in one go by pipeling them.

I have first try to use a Task.Run Action to call Redis but the problem that I am observing is that under stress, the memory of my webapi keep climbing.
The memory is full of **System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem**[] objects with the folowing code :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/values/testpostfireforget")]
    public  ApiResult<int> DeleteFromBasketId([FromBody] int basketId)
    {

        var response = new DeleteFromBasketResponse<int>();

        var cpt = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);

            Task.Run(async () => {
                await db.StringSetAsync($"BASKET_TO_DELETE_{cpt}",cpt.ToString())
                         .ConfigureAwait(false); 
            });  
           return response;
     }
```

So I think that under stress my api keep enqueing background task in memory and execute them one after the other as fast as it can but less than the request coming in...

So I am searching for a way to have **only one** long lived background thread running with the asp.net webapi, that could capture the commands to send to Redis and execute them **by pipeling them**.

I was thinking in runnning a background task by implementing IHostedService interface,  but it seems that in this case the background task would not share any state with my current http request. So implementing  a IhostedService would be handy for a scheduled background task but not in my case, or I do not know how...

Comment: You don't need to Task.Run an async Task. Just await it directly. That is not fire-and-forget, but if you don't await then the response will end. That redis operation should not take significant time.

Comment: Yes I have not set the fireandforget command flag. I am comparing various way of doing it : I have already test the limit with awaiting this command, and it's very  fast. But I am searching if there is a way to push the work on a background thread in order to execute even more command to redis per second.

Comment: `that could capture the commands to send to Redis and execute them by pipeling them`
You do not need to handle pipelining - StackExchange.Redis will handle it for you internally. The client may not send each individual message independently but rather group them and send it over the network all at once. See [Pipelining](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/PipelinesMultiplexers#pipelining) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [StackExchange.Redis documentation](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Basics.html#sync-vs-async-vs-fire-and-forget) you can use `CommandFlags.FireAndForget` flag:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/values/testpostfireforget")]
public  ApiResult<int> DeleteFromBasketId([FromBody] int basketId)
{

    var response = new DeleteFromBasketResponse<int>();
    var cpt = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);

    db.StringSet($"BASKET_TO_DELETE_{cpt}", cpt.ToString(), flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);  

    return response;
}
```

**Edit 1: another solution based on comment**

You can use pub/sub approach. Something like this should work:

```
public class MessageBatcher
{
    private readonly IDatabase target;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Action<IDatabaseAsync>> tasks = new();
    private Task worker;

    public MessageBatcher(IDatabase target) => this.target = target;

    public void AddMessage(Action<IDatabaseAsync> task) => tasks.Add(task);
    
    public IDisposable Start(int batchSize)
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(state =>
        {
            var count = 0;
            var tokenSource = (CancellationTokenSource) state;
            var box = new StrongBox<IBatch>(target.CreateBatch());
            tokenSource.Token.Register(b => ((StrongBox<IBatch>)b).Value.Execute(), box);
            foreach (var task in tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable(tokenSource.Token))
            {
                var batch = box.Value;
                task(batch);
                if (++count == batchSize)
                {
                    batch.Execute();
                    box.Value = target.CreateBatch();
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            
        }, cancellationTokenSource, cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);

        return new Disposer(worker, cancellationTokenSource);
    }

    private class Disposer : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Task worker;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

        public Disposer(Task worker, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource) => (this.worker, this.tokenSource) = (worker, tokenSource);

        public void Dispose()
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            worker.Wait();
            tokenSource.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private readonly MessageBatcher batcher;

ctor(MessageBatcher  batcher) // ensure that passed `handler` is singleton and already already started
{
    this.batcher= batcher;
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/values/testpostfireforget")]
public  ApiResult<int> DeleteFromBasketId([FromBody] int basketId)
{
    var response = new DeleteFromBasketResponse<int>();
    var cpt = Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);

    batcher.AddMessage(db => db.StringSetAsync($"BASKET_TO_DELETE_{cpt}", cpt.ToString(), flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget));  

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Oleh, I have already test this flag. I am trying now to benchmark a way to delay and batch the commands in one go.